# Check parameters passed to constructor when using initialization lists - C++

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a class containing vectors as data members.

When calling the constructor, I wish for said data members to be initialized by the copy constructor and not default initialized (to empty vector object), therefore I use an initialization list.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    vector<double> V;
    vector<double> A;
    vector<double> B;

    MyStruct (vector<double> vee, vector< vector <double> > mat);
};

MyStruct::MyStruct (vector<double> vee, vector< vector <double> > mat)
    : V(vee),
    A(mat[0]),
    B(mat[1])    
{
    /* Rest of the constructor here*/ 
}
```

My questions are:

- Does doing this improves efficiency vs. permitting the default initialization and the using other methods? e.g. doing

  `V.assign(vee)`
- Is there a way to have checks and errors/messages be returned by the constructor before either default-initialization or list-initialization takes place?

I would like for the ctor to e.g. halt if the size of the `vector<vector<double>>` > 2, for the obvious reason that otherwise the above would produce a seg fault and I would like this process to be automated when the constructor is called.

Comment: Is `std::array<std::vector<double>, 2u>` an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you want to avoid an exception you could do something like this. It uses the ternary operator to check the size of the `vector` and use an empty `vector` to initialize if one is not present in `mat`.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    vector<double> V;
    vector<double> A;
    vector<double> B;

    MyStruct (vector<double> vee, vector< vector <double> > mat);
};

MyStruct::MyStruct (vector<double> vee, vector< vector <double> > mat)
    : V(vee),
    A(mat.size() < 1 ? vector<double>():mat[0]),
    B(mat.size() < 2 ? vector<double>():mat[1])
{
    // If you then want to throw your own exception:
    if(mat.size() < 2)
        throw std::range_error("accessing mat");

    // alternatively set a flag
    if(mat.size() < 2)
        this->good = false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this very dangerous? My main goal is to avoid the exception and possibly return a message that will tell me that a mistake in passing a parameter has been done (instead of a generic code dump message). This instead hides the problem, leaving me with an undefined object that I am unaware off and that I will try to use later on, generating further errors.

Comment: @ThreeDiag I have added some error reporting possibilities but it depends what constitutes an "undefined object". Usually such things *should* be prevented by the constructor throwing an exception forcing the error checking to the calling code.

Comment: you can throw from the ternary operator